# Can't execute a jQuery function more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
$('#edit').on("click", function () {
    $('#edit').text('click1');
    $('table a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('table a').css("cursor", "default");

        }
    });
    $('#edit').click(function () {
        $('#edit').unbind();
        $('#edit-message-placeholder').empty();
        $('#edit').text('click2');
        $("table tbody").sortable("disable");
        $('table a').unbind()
        $('table a').css("cursor", "auto");

    });
});
```

On first click, I want it to change the text of `div#edit`. On second click, it will change the text to something else. On third click, the function will behave as though it was clicked the first time.

I tried to find a solution online, but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're approaching this incorrectly. You don't need to bind/unbind event handlers. You only need one event handler that alternates in functionality:

**JavaScript**

```
var isOkay = true;
$("p").click(function () {
    if (isOkay) {
        $(this).text("1st click");
    } else {
        $(this).text("2nd click");
    }
    isOkay = !isOkay;
})
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Click me!</p>
```

Every time the `<p>` is clicked, it performs an action and then switches the value of a boolean variable, `isOkay`. This means that it will alternate between the `if` and `else` block. Note that the `isOkay` variable is held outside the scope of the `$("p").click(...)` event handler.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/st9Tr/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

Use the `data` property to temporarily save the counter data

```
<button id="edit" data-count="1">1</button>


function doWork(val){
    alert(val);
};
$('#edit').on("click", function () {

    if($(this).data('count') == ""){
        $(this).data('count') = 1;
    }
    var count = parseInt($(this).data('count'));
    if (count == 1){
        doWork(count);
    }else if (count == 2){
        doWork(count);
    }else if (count == 3){
        doWork(count);
    }
    count += 1
    count = count >= 4 ? 1: count;
    $(this).data('count', count);
    $(this).html($(this).data('count'));
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pt3zE/1/

Comment: You could always do `count %= 2` and just keep it as `if (count == 0) { ...} else {...}` and then just increment `count` each time. Making a specific case for `count == 3` isn't necessary if it's just going to repeat `count == 1`.

Comment: I kept that one intentionally, because the OP might need more cases to handle, it might not be only 3.